# OpenMRS How to add/save new fields in Patient Registration?

Tags: xforms, openmrs

I'm complectly new to OpenMRS. I have installed openmrs 1.12 and build(8f283e) in Windows OS.
I need to add following custom new fields in Patient Registration Form.

1. Mother's Name(Text field and Required field)
2. Emergency Contact Name(Text field)
3. Emergency Contact Phone Number(numeric field & validation)
4. Marital Status(Drop down and Required field)
   and many more fields I need to add.

I have install the **XFORM** module and overwrite  the existing Patient registration form & I created the custom fields as I mentioned above filed.

I'm able to create/save the Patient record but new custom filed values are not stored in the DB level.

Some one please help me to , How to save  custom fields in Patient Registration?

Answer (score 0):

You have add person attributes first, then with the ID create a JSON code and add on "Manage App", if you read the documentation:  https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Registration+App+Configuration

you can see